# "Advertisement Management" isn't visible in the administrator panel

Tags: module, forum, phpbb

phpBB Forum. I want to include "Advertisement Management" Mod, but after installation it isn't visible in the administrator panel.

When I change the formation of the objects in the administrator panel, I can see Advertisement Management, but it isn't there in the end.

Forum language is german and mod language englisch.
phpBB Version: 3.0.10

Comment: You could maybe get support in the irc channels here https://www.phpbb.com/support/irc/

Comment: Or visit https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/mod/advertisement_management/support/

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed it successfully on also template edits it should work you just only need to add ads

visit your ACP in general tab left side menu item you shold see Board configuration under that settings you will see configrations for Advertisement Management MOD